# Swift saving and retrieving custom object from UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding

I have this in Playground using Swift 3, Xcode 8.0:

```
import Foundation
class Person: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
    required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String
        let age = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "age") as! Int
        self.init(
            name: name,
            age: age
        )
    }
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
        aCoder.encode(age, forKey: "age")
    }
}
```

---

create array of Person

```
let newPerson = Person(name: "Joe", age: 10)
var people = [Person]()
people.append(newPerson)
```

---

encode the array

```
let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: people)
print("encodedData: \(encodedData))")
```

---

save to userDefaults

```
let userDefaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard()
userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "people")
userDefaults.synchronize()
```

---

check

```
print("saved object: \(userDefaults.object(forKey: "people"))")
```

---

retreive from userDefaults

```
if let data = userDefaults.object(forKey: "people") {
    let myPeopleList = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data as! Data)
    print("myPeopleList: \(myPeopleList)")
}else{
    print("There is an issue")
}
```

---

just check the archived data

```
if let myPeopleList = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: encodedData){
   print("myPeopleList: \(myPeopleList)")
}else{
   print("There is an issue")
}
```

I'm not able to correctly save the data object to userDefaults, and in addition, the check at the bottom creates the error:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The "check" line also shows the saved object is nil. Is this an error in my object's NSCoder?

Comment: `if let data = userDefaults.data(forKey: "people"), let myPeopleList = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? [Person] {`

Comment: I put this in a single page test app and same result, with your suggested change.  It looks like it may be an issue with the object coder.  The error I get is: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value and its at the line  "if let data = userDefaults.data(forKey: "people") {
            let myPeopleList = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data )"

Answer (score 94, accepted):

**Swift 4 or later**

You can once again save/test your values in a Playground

---

UserDefaults need to be tested in a real project. Note: No need to force synchronize. If you want to test the coding/decoding in a playground you can save the data to a plist file in the document directory using the keyed archiver. You need also to fix some issues in your class:

---

```
class Person: NSObject, NSCoding {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        self.name = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String ?? ""
        self.age = decoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "age")
    }
    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
        coder.encode(age, forKey: "age")
    }
}
```

---

Testing:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        do {
            // setting a value for a key
            let newPerson = Person(name: "Joe", age: 10)
            var people = [Person]()
            people.append(newPerson)
            let encodedData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: people, requiringSecureCoding: false)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "people")
            // retrieving a value for a key
            if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "people"),
                let myPeopleList = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? [Person] {
                myPeopleList.forEach({print($0.name, $0.age)})  // Joe 10
            }                    
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Leo, there were a couple of changes - in required init: self.age = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "age") as? Int ?? 0 to set the default for age

Comment: Sorry - just the one change

Comment: @user773881 Have you tried my code as it is? I've tested it here and it was working fine

Comment: Yes I did and it works as its own project, but isn't it necessary to also use ?? for nil coalescing on "self.age = decoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "age")" to assure a default Int?

Comment: @LeoDabus, bro could you please loot at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44667335/how-to-pass-prefs-value-data-from-view-controller-to-inside-table-view-cell-with  ?

Comment: @LeoDabus Any Luck regarding handling `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile:` when corrupted/ file not exists. Or can we apply checks ? Since `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject` not throws hence we can't add `try catch`. Any workaround?

Comment: Best answer in my opinion. Don't forget to import that NSCoding

Answer (score 49):

```
let age = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "age") as! Int
```

This has been changed for Swift 3; this no longer works for value types. The correct syntax is now:

```
let age = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "age")
```

There are associated decode...() functions for various different types:

```
let myBool = aDecoder.decodeBoolean(forKey: "myStoredBool")
let myFloat = aDecoder.decodeFloat(forKey: "myStoredFloat")
```

Edit: [Full list of all possible decodeXXX functions in Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscoder)

Edit:

Another important note: If you have previously saved data that was encoded with an older version of Swift, those values **must** be decoded using decodeObject(), *however* once you re-encode the data using encode(...) it can no longer be decoded with decodeObject() if it's a value type. Therefore Markus Wyss's answer will allow you to handle the case where the data was encoded using either Swift version:

```
self.age = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "age") as? Int ?? aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "age")
```

Comment: Ridiculous there was no Xcode warning that old code would break in Swift 3. Thanks for posting this!

Comment: What if the key isn't an Int but a Bool, for instance? How do you safely decode the value?

Comment: To clarify `String` is a value type in Swift, but there is no `decodeString` function ... so the old way still applies for a `String`. Not sure why, though.

Comment: If it's a bool, then you'd need to use the `decodeBoolean()` function in combination with the ?? operator, just like the Int example. `self.age = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "myBoolean") as? Bool ?? aDecoder.decodeBoolean(forKey: "myBoolean")` Not sure why String isn't included; anything that doesn't have a dedicated function seems to still work with `decodeObject()`

Comment: You just saved my day! Thanks!

Comment: How to manage decode for swift3 if a key does not exist ? with Swift 2 I had: if let ageTmp = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "age") as? Int {
            self.age = ageTemp
        }else{           
            self.age= 0             
        }

Comment: You should use if(aDecoder.containsValue(forKey: "age")){...} to see if the value exists before you try to decode it.

Comment: @ibuprofane @RemyNL Is there a similar caveat for using `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject()` vs the various `decodeXXX` methods on `NSKeyedUnarchiver`? If so, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 22):

**In Swift 4:**

You can use Codable to save and retrieve custom object from the Userdefaults. If you're doing it frequently then you can add as extension and use it like below.

```
extension UserDefaults {

   func save<T:Encodable>(customObject object: T, inKey key: String) {
       let encoder = JSONEncoder()
       if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(object) {
           self.set(encoded, forKey: key)
       }
   }

   func retrieve<T:Decodable>(object type:T.Type, fromKey key: String) -> T? {
       if let data = self.data(forKey: key) {
           let decoder = JSONDecoder()
           if let object = try? decoder.decode(type, from: data) {
               return object
           }else {
               print("Couldnt decode object")
               return nil
           }
       }else {
           print("Couldnt find key")
           return nil
       }
   }

}
```

Your Class must follow Codable. Its just a typealias for both Encodable & Decodable Protocol.

```
class UpdateProfile: Codable {
  //Your stuffs
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let updateProfile = UpdateProfile()

//To save the object
UserDefaults.standard.save(customObject: updateProfile, inKey: "YourKey")

//To retrieve the saved object
let obj = UserDefaults.standard.retrieve(object: UpdateProfile.self, fromKey: "YourKey")
```

For more Encoding and Decoding Custom types, Please go through the [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

**Update: Swift 5 New Solution**

**Testable UserDefaults with Property Wrapper + Combine**

```
@propertyWrapper struct UserDefaultsStore<T: Codable> {
    let key: String
    let storage: UserDefaultsStorage
    private let subject: PassthroughSubject<[T], Never> = .init()
    
    var wrappedValue: [T] {
        get {
            guard let data = storage.object(forKey: key) as? Data,
               let models = try? JSONDecoder().decode([T].self, from: data) else {
                return []
            }
            return models
           
        }
        set {
            if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue) {
                storage.set(encoded, forKey: key)
                subject.send(wrappedValue)
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    var projectedValue: AnyPublisher<[T], Never> {
        return subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

protocol UserDefaultsStorage {
    func object(forKey key: String) -> Any?
    func set(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String)
}

extension UserDefaults: UserDefaultsStorage {}

struct DataToSave: Codable {}



//Usage
// Main Target
enum StorageSettings {
    @UserDefaultsStore<DataToSave>(key:"stored_data", storage: DIInjecter.userDefaults)
    static var storeSomething: [DataToSave]
    
}
struct DependenciesInjecter {
    lazy var userDefaults: UserDefaultsStorage = UserDefaults.standard
}
var DIInjecter = DependenciesInjecter()

// Test Target
class UserDefaultsStorageMock: UserDefaultsStorage {
    var values: [String: Any]
    init(values: [String : Any] = [:]) {
        self.values = values
    }

    func object(forKey key: String) -> Any? {
        return values[key]
    }

    func set(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String) {
        values[key] = value
    }
}

extension DependenciesInjecter {
    static var mock: DependenciesInjecter {
        Self(userDefaults: UserDefaultsStorageMock())
    }
}
// Put it in setup func
DIInjecter = .mock
```

Comment: great one brother.!

Comment: @ayanchakraborty Thank you..!

Comment: This is by far the newest, cleanest approach in swift. Amazing work brother.

Comment: Hello sir my protocol is Decodable. how can i save this

Comment: @Maulikshah being `Decodable` doesn't mean you can also encode an object. You need to use `Codable` which means `Encodable & Decodable`

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
self.age = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "age") as? Int ?? aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "age")
```

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 5, I would use a property wrapper to simply the code:

````
/// A type that adds an interface to use the user’s defaults with codable types
///
/// Example:
/// ```
/// @UserDefaultCodable(key: "nameKey", defaultValue: "Root") var name: String
/// ```
/// Adding the attribute @UserDefaultCodable the property works reading and writing from user's defaults
/// with any codable type
///
@propertyWrapper public struct UserDefaultCodable<T: Codable> {
    private let key: String
    private let defaultValue: T

    /// Initialize the key and the default value.
    public init(key: String, defaultValue: T) {
        self.key = key
        self.defaultValue = defaultValue
    }

    public var wrappedValue: T {
        get {
            // Read value from UserDefaults
            guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? Data else {
                // Return defaultValue when no data in UserDefaults
                return defaultValue
            }

            // Convert data to the desire data type
            let value = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            return value ?? defaultValue
        }
        set {
            // Convert newValue to data
            let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue)

            // Set value to UserDefaults
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
````

Comment: `UserDefaults` has a method exactly for this purpose called [`data(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1409590-data). Btw setting a default value when decoding fails it is definitely not what you want.

Comment: When encoding fails it will actually remove any existing value setting it to `nil`. You should handle the errors