# NSKeyedArchiver does not work in Swift 3 (Xcode 8)

Tags: swift3, xcode8, ios10

I have migrated my project to Swift 3 and `NSKeyedArchiver` does not work. I actually have a runtime error when trying to decode object like this:

```
let startDayTime = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: Key.startDayTime) as! Int
```

It worked perfectly in Swift 2.2 in Xcode 7.3. Has anybody else faced such troubles?

P.S. I have this error on both Simulator and Device.

Comment: Please add your error output.

Comment: It could be either that the object was `nil` or that the cast to `Int` failed. You should look at the result of `decodeObject` before the forced casting and see which is the problem. Also, FYI, when dealing with integers, you can use `decodeInteger(forKey: )`.

Comment: You should add solution as an answer

Comment: Apple is playing with our nerves. I have been trying to debug this for a couple of hours now. It seems unbelievable, but they had to make decodeObjece as? Int fail!!!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It appears that this only happens on the Swift 2 to Swift 3 update boundary when a NSData blob archived with a `NSKeyedArchiver` in Swift 2 is opened with a `NSKeyedUnarchiver` in Swift 3. My guess is that on Swift 2, the `Bool` and `Int` are encoded as `NSNumber`, but in Swift 3, they are encoded as raw `Bool` and `Int` types. I believe the following test supports this claim:

This works in Swift 3 to unarchive a `Bool` encoded in Swift 2, but returns `nil` if the Bool was encoded in Swift 3:

```
let visible = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "visible") as? Bool
```

This works in Swift 3 to unarchive a `Bool` encoded in Swift 3, but crashes if the Bool was encoded in Swift 2:

```
let visible = aDecoder.decodeBool(forKey: "visible")
```

My solution is:

```
let visible = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "visible") as? Bool ?? aDecoder.decodeBool(forKey: "visible")
```

Comment: thanks, this worked for me. such a subtle error, they really need to document stuff like this and save devs time.

Comment: This should be the best answer because it safely allows customers to upgrade apps running swift 2 to 3.

Answer (score 8):

I solved this problem by using:

```
decodeInteger(forKey key: String)
```

instead of:

```
decodeObject(forKey key: String)
```

For some reason AnyObject does not cast to Integer in Swift 3, though it did in Swift 2.2

Comment: Want to mention the same for Bool.

Comment: I'm still having issues if updating from encodeObject (swift 2), decodeInteger (swift 3) still crashes my app :(

Comment: I just found this post. I am now dealing with a somewhat similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41224991/nskeyedarchiver-nskeyedunarchiver-swift-3-0. Were you using NSKeyedUnarchiver as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here is solution:

```
class Person: NSObject, NSCoding {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    required init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        self.name = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String ?? ""
        self.age = decoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "age")
    }

    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
        coder.encode(age, forKey: "age")
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let newPerson = Person(name: "Joe", age: 10)
        var people = [Person]()
        people.append(newPerson)
        let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: people)
        UserDefaults.standard().set(encodedData, forKey: "people")
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard().data(forKey: "people"),
            myPeopleList = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? [Person] {
            myPeopleList.forEach({print( $0.name, $0.age)})  // Joe 10
        } else {
            print("There is an issue")
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Reference: [Swift 3 saving and retrieving custom object from userDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980432/swift-3-saving-and-retrieving-custom-object-from-userdefaults)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**:

I adopt the *double question mark* ([??](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72)) method and it work like a charm **in only one line**.

If val is not nil than it is unwrapped and the value returned. If it is nil then `aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "val")` returned:

```
self.val = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "val") as? Int ?? aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "val")
```