# How to save data to NSUserDefaults in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, swift3, nskeyedarchiver

I want to save my data into NSUSerDefaults in Swift3 in:

```
func a() {
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let sessionData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: session)
    userDefaults.set(session, forKey: "SpotifySession")
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}
```

but it crashes in

```
NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: session)
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: What is `session`?

Comment: NSUserDefaults supports the following data types: NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, NSDictionary and NSData 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980432/swift-3-saving-and-retrieving-custom-object-from-userdefaults

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not encode and decode method in your session class.
If your session is custom class then you should write the following two methods, without that archive won't work.

**Code :**

Objective C Version:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
 [encoder encodeObject:self.session_property1 forKey:@"session_property1"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.session_property2 forKey:@"session_property2"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        //decode properties, other class vars
        self.ession_property1 = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"ession_property1"];
        self.ession_property2 = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"ession_property2"];
}
    return self;
}
```

Here session_property1 and session_property2 are considered as string, if your variable is other than string you need to format it accordingly.

After these in your cut on class, if you will use `archiveData` method as you did, then it will archive the data and then you can set those data to `NSUserDefault`

**Swift Version :**

```
required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    self.state = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "state") as? String
    self.country = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "country") as? String
    self.zip = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "zip") as? String
    self.locality = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "locality") as? String
    self.city = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "city") as? String
    self.latitude = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "latitude") as? Double
    self.longitude = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "longitude") as? Double
}

func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
    coder.encode(state, forKey: "state")
    coder.encode(country, forKey: "country")
    coder.encode(zip, forKey: "zip")
    coder.encode(locality, forKey: "locality")
    coder.encode(city, forKey: "city")
    coder.encode(latitude, forKey: "latitude")
    coder.encode(longitude, forKey: "longitude")
}
```

I hope it will help you.
Happy coding ...

Comment: you write solution in objective-c and the question is asking for swift coding version

Comment: @AmrAngry, Thanks for reminding me. I was just giving the hint with objective C by that time. But no worries now, I have updated my answer now with Swift.

Answer (score -1):

I think, this is the right way to save data in NSUserDefaults:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject("Coding Explorer", forKey: "userNameKey")
```

Comment: Saving data in NSUserDefaults has already been explained hundreds of times, your answer adds nothing. Moreover, OP is specifically asking for a Swift 3 version, which you don't give...