# Swift 3 Xcode 8 - SwiftValue encodeWithCoder - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: swift3, xcode8, nscoding

My custom objects conform to the NSCoding protocol with the following methods

```
required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init()

    createdDate = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "created_date") as? Date
    userId = decoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "user_id")
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(createdDate, forKey: "created_date")
    aCoder.encode(userId, forKey: "user_id")
}
```

This is the correct method name for the nscoding protocol in Swift 3, however the app is crashing with the error `SwiftValue encodeWithCoder - unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Clearly this method is not available, so why is it not recognized?

Reference at https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscoding

Here is the archiver method I made

```
func encodeObject(_ defaults:UserDefaults, object:NSCoding?, key:String) {
    if (object != nil) {
        let encodedObject = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: object)
        defaults.set(encodedObject, forKey: key)
    } else {
        defaults.removeObject(forKey: key)
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case, I was migrating app from swift 2 to 4, and the encoding / decoding was not implementing well . so I just followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/37983027/5561910

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to archive an optional. Replace this line:

```
if (object != nil) {
```

with:

```
if let object = object {
```

Comment: Wow thank  you for the clarification. That seems to have fixed it. I suppose nil comparison would work but I'd have to mark it non optional.

Comment: if let self.eventDataArr.count = self.eventDataArr.count
in my case object is an array ,
I am getting below error 
Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer

Comment: if  self.eventDataArr.count > 0  {
} this condition worked for me thanks