# swift 3 - remove objects from array that exist in another array

Tags: arrays, swift3

I have an array with Contact objects inside.

Then I have another array with Users.

```
class Contact: NSObject {

    var name: String?
    var phoneNumber: String?
    var phoneNumberFormatted: String?

    init(name: String, phoneNumber: String?, phoneNumberFormatted: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
        self.phoneNumberFormatted = phoneNumberFormatted
    }
}


 class User: NSObject {

        var name: String?
    }
```

How can I remove a Contact object from the `[Contact]` if I have a User in my `[User]` with a matching name?

I know how to do it through loops but what is most efficient way?

Comment: A `PhoneNumber` object has a `phoneNumber` field. That doesn't make much sense, does it?

Comment: I changed the phoneNumber objects name to Contact. Thanks for your help @AlexanderMomchliov

Comment: Does it make sense for a contact to not have a name?

Comment: No. The contact should have a name. @AlexanderMomchliov

Comment: Then why is the name an optional?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov I've always safely unwrapped my object properties. I think a better practice is to just not make things that are required optional. Thanks again man really

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130265/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-walker).

Comment: @Walker Is there any reason to make it a NSObject? Otherwise you shouldn't. Also if the fields are required you should use let, make it non optional and add a required initializer for the property(ies)

Comment: No specific reason. What type of object do you think it should be? @LeoDabus Thank you!

Comment: @Walker just remove it `class Contact {
    let name: String
    let phoneNumber: String
    let phoneNumberFormatted: String
    required init(name: String, phoneNumber: String, phoneNumberFormatted: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
        self.phoneNumberFormatted = phoneNumberFormatted
    }
}
`

Comment: If you are not going to make your class NSCoding compliant you don't need to subclass NSObject

Comment: @LeoDabus all of my model objects are NSObjects. What are the benefits vs just making them a class of their own? I'm sure I'm not benefiting from anything that making it an NSObject has to bring. Thanks

Comment: You are coding in Swift, no need to subclass NSObject unless you have a specific reason (to behave as NSObject)

Comment: If you need an instance where it is needed you can take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37983027/2303865

Comment: @Walker You want to remove filter `[Contact]` array and remove objects that name is matched with `[User]` array, right?

Comment: @Walker Subclassing `NSObject` implicitly also acts as if you added the `@objc` attribute. It will make your class available to the Objective C runtime library, which brings many new features, but also sizeable performance decreases. Subclass it only if there's a reason. One such reason is to make a class `NSCoding` compliant, in order to use CoreData.

Comment: If you don't have a reason to be using Objective C functionality, then avoid it. This simple model class is a prime candidate for being a struct, rather than a class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best (most computationally efficient) way to do this for non-trivial array sizes is to precompute a set from the array you need to repeatedly search, and filter your other array, keeping elements only if they're not found in the set.

This leverages the `O(1)` lookup performance of `Set`. The algorithm as a whole is `O(userPhoneNumbers.count + contacts.count)`

```
let userPhoneNumbers = Set(users.lazy.map{ $0.phoneNumber })
let filteredContacts = self.contacts.filter{ !userPhoneNumbers.contains($0.phoneNumber) }
```

Comment: Alex, I'm trying to filter by a property that the objects in both arrays have. The answer is not clear to me. Mind expanding a bit? Thanks man

Comment: Are you familiar with map/reduce/filter?