# Swift 3 caching

Tags: ios, swift, caching, store

Is there an easy way to store my app's data in Swift 3?

I would like to store a single object in some way. I tried `UserDefaults.standard.set(my_object, forKey: "my_object")` but it doesn't seem to work.

I put this code in AppDelegate.swift in `func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication)`

Also, I would like to read this object back in `func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool`, when the application starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserDefaults is the simplest way.

> I put this code in *AppDelegate.swift* in `func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication)`

Well, that's pretty silly, because that method is basically never called. Save information out to UserDefaults somewhere such that your code will actually run. `applicationDidEnterBackground(_:)` and `applicationWillResignActive(_:)` are possible choices, but the way to be certain is simply to save the information out whenever the information changes.

> Also, I would like to read this object back in `func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool`, when the application starts.

Well, 99.9% of the time your application starts, that method won't be called. But if that method *is* called, fine, go ahead and read the object back in.

Comment: My object is not in Property List (it's not a standard type, like NSDate or NSNumber). How can I add this kind of object to UserDefaults?

Comment: Very good question! But that is a question that has been answered many times on Stack Overflow, so just do a search. You can store anything in UserDefaults; you just have to make it archivable into an NSData, and do so. (Might help you to glance at the discussion in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch36.html#_saving_and_reading_files )

Comment: @BartoszWoźniak For storing a custom class object in UserDefaults, read something about NSCoding protocol, encode-decode, archive-unarchive

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980432/swift-3-saving-and-retrieving-custom-object-from-userdefaults