# Swift: how i can persist data when the app will be closed

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, append

I made an .append to an array like this:

```
@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField? = nil
var array = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    array.append((textField?.text?.lowercased())!)
}
```

This works good, but how could I save the appended strings even when the app will be closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the array to UserDefaults, and read it back on app launch.

```
var itemsArray = [String]()
```

...

```
itemsArray = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "arrayKey") as? [String] ?? []
```

And to save it:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(itemsArray, forKey: "arrayKey")
```

Comment: I start learning swift from 3 weeks ago, how I save array in UserDefaults?

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: App data should not be saved to user defaults. Write the array to a file (plist).

Comment: UserDefaults has a specific method for loading arrays   `UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "arrayKey") as? [String] ?? []`

Comment: and set is wrong. should be `UserDefaults.standard.set(itemsArray, forKey: "arrayKey")`

Comment: Data in UserDefaults should only contain user preference, like volume, language, currency etc.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: but if I have multiple arrays? I have five buttons, when I press a button, the string goes in one of the five arrays. @LeoDabus

Comment: You can have it all inside a property list file as suggested by @rmaddy

Comment: you will need to use NSKeyedArchiver to convert your object to data and save it to disk

Comment: Note that your objects must conform to NSCoding http://stackoverflow.com/a/37983027/2303865

Comment: rmaddy is right, saving app data to UserDefaults is bad form. Better to save it to a plist file in your documents directory.