# iOS Swift Storing Realm Object to UserDefaults.standard

Tags: ios, swift3, realm, nsuserdefaults

Here is my Realm Object:

```
PracticeAreaEntity {
    id = 0;
    c_id = 21871;
    c_number = C.C/1/2016;
    c_title = Title Here;
    date = 2017-04-07T00:00:00.000Z;
    description2 = ;
    object = {"id":205039,"c_id":21871,"name":"07-04-2017","s_time":"2017-04-07T00:00:00.000Z","e_time":"2017-04-08T00:00:00.000Z","creator":"system","created_by_id":null,"description":null,"c_at":"2017-03-26T00:11:52.134Z","u_at":"2017-04-07T01:00:27.396Z","judge":null,"phearing":null,"google_event_id":null,"is_completed":false,"business":null,"last_notified":"2017-04-07T01:00:27.382Z","ng_date":null,"b_date":null,"b_d_available":false};
    p_id = 205039;
    subject = 07-04-2017;
    type = Event;
}
```

I need to store this realm object to UserDefault.standard and get values back in another page. And here is my UserDefults code:

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
userDefaults.set(filteredtotalContactArray[indexPath.row], forKey: "SelectedPractice")
userDefaults.synchronize()
```

filteredtotalContactArray[indexPath.row] equals to values that I have specified before as Realm Object. But I am getting error as

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object
```

Comment: Why are u try to store the object in `UserDefault ` while using `Realm`? Thats a bad practice, also, store custom object in `UserDefault` require confront to `NSCoding` protocol, which will convert your object into Data

Comment: In tableview I'm displaying list of object in my realm. I need to store selected index path.row value into UserDefaults.standard

Comment: we can't store custom object  directly, you need to go for Keyarchiver concept

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980432/swift-3-saving-and-retrieving-custom-object-from-userdefaults

Comment: I have try that too. Here is the code to store values:                                           `let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
            let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: (filteredtotalContactArray[indexPath.row] as AnyObject))
            userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "SelectedPractice")
            userDefaults.synchronize()`                  But it won't works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to supply conformance methods to `NSCoding` for your Realm models in order to be able to persist them to `UserDefaults`.

However, I'd encourage you to use Realm to persist Realm models given that you're already using Realm in your app.