# UserDefaults in AppDelegate.Swift not working

Tags: swift, xcode

```
var window: UIWindow?

 func application(_ application: UIApplication, options: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]?) -> Bool {
    UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [
        bestScoreKey: 1_000_000.0
        ])
    return true
}

func application2(_ application: UIApplication, options: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]?) -> Bool {
    UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [
        coinsKey: 0

        ])

    return true
}

public func application3(_ application: UIApplication, options: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]?) -> Bool {
   UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [

        standardHSKey: 0

        ])

    return true
}
```

Up above are the three functions I have in AppDelegate.Swift. For some reason the top two functions work but not the bottom one. Here are the ViewControllers below. In this ViewController the data saves.

```
var fastestScore: Double = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: bestScoreKey) {
    didSet {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(fastestScore, forKey: bestScoreKey)
    }
}

var coinsTotal: Int = Int(UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: coinsKey)) {

    didSet {

    UserDefaults.standard.set(coinsTotal, forKey: coinsKey)

    }
}
```

However, it does not save the data in this viewController

```
 var highScore: Int = Int(UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: standardHSKey){

 didSet {

    UserDefaults.standard.set(highScore, forKey: standardHSKey)

        }
}
```

I don't know what the problem is. When I substitute an integer for highScore it works but it does not save the data to Userdefaults. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3 saving and retrieving custom object from userDefaults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980432/swift-3-saving-and-retrieving-custom-object-from-userdefaults)

Comment: .synchronize() not called

Comment: @g where would I put synchronize()

Comment: after you change anything on UserDefaults

Comment: @ReidBrown `where would I put synchronize()` Nowhere. This is not needed anymore since iOS8. People telling others to add `synchronize()` didn't update their knowledge about this, this is just an habit that is now useless. It's explained in the documentation (and verified by tests).