# How to save Singletone object in NSUserDefaults Swift2.3?

Tags: swift, userdefaults

```
class AddBodyMeasurments
{
    static let sharedInstance = AddBodyMeasurments()
    var BodyMeasurements:AddMeasurment!

    private init()
    {
        BodyMeasurements = AddMeasurment.init(json: [:])
    }
    func SaveValue(value:AddMeasurment)
    {
        BodyMeasurements = value
    }
}
```

I have tried the following :

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(obj)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "folks")
```

I am getting Following error :

> 2017-08-17 12:37:46.009 Fiyre[15749:1061631] *** NSForwarding:
>   warning: object 0x7fca71d18700 of class 'Fiyre.AddBodyMeasurments'
>   does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
>   Unrecognized selector -[Fiyre.AddBodyMeasurments
>   replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:]

Thanks Advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980432/swift-3-saving-and-retrieving-custom-object-from-userdefaults

Comment: Thanks , But I have to store singleton Object

Answer (score 1):

The error message reveals that the class does not inherit from `NSObject`.

- Inheritance from `NSObject` is required to conform to `NSCoding`.
- `NSCoding` is required to archive custom classes.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you're not saving a singleton object but an object in general. After you deserialize you object (get its instance from NSUserDefaults) you will store that instance to your singleton object or more precisely you will instantiate your singleton object with deserialized object.

```
class AddBodyMeasurments
{
    static let sharedInstance = AddBodyMeasurments()
    var bodyMeasurements:AddMeasurment!

    private init()
    {
        // deserializing object of AddBodyMeasurments type from NSDefaults.
        let deserialized = getFromUserDefaults()

        self.bodyMeasurements = deserialized.bodyMeasurements
    }
}
```