# Swift 3: Custom Array of classes for core data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, ios10

I'm currently trying to create a core data model which consists of an array of a custom class/struct. I'm free to chooses either class or a struct for the model.

The Struct looks a little bit like this:

```
public struct takenImage{
  var image: UIImage
  var label: String
  var time: NSDate
}
```

now I have my Core Data Model which has an entity called LogPhotos containing the attributes:

`timestamp` of type `Date`

`pictureArray` of type `Transformable`

Now I would like to have my `pictureArray` contain an Array of the `takenImage` struct. This is important because I need to call later for certain values from that struct. It's neccessary to get the image from that array for instance.

The issue is, that when I try to save the context it crashes with SIGABRT and `uncaught exeption 'NSInvalidArgumentExeption' reason [myApp.takenImage:] unrecognized selector sent to instance`
I guess it's because it cannot store the `[takenImage]` to the `transformable`.

What could I do? I'd like to avoid having another core data entity if possible. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Why are you avoiding another entity? This is the sort of thing that would fit perfectly into another related entity.

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980432/swift-3-saving-and-retrieving-custom-object-from-userdefaults

Comment: @Abizern The issue is that i'd like to store the images directly in the struct instead of storing the url in the coredata model.

Comment: Performance will be a lot better if you don't have to load the image when the fault fires.