# Store Decodable struct to Userdefaults

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `Decodable` struct like so...

```
struct BestWishes: Decodable {

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case customerID = "customer_id"
        case birthDate = "birth_date"
         case type = "type"
        case customerName = "customer_name"
        case mobileNo = "mobile_number"
    }
    let customerID: Int
    let date: String
    let type: String
    let customerName : String
    let mobileNumber: Int

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        customerID = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .customerID)
        type = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
        if type == "anniversary_date" {
            date = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .anniversaryDate)
        } else {
            date = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .birthDate)
        }
        customerName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .customerName)
        mobileNumber = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .mobileNo)
    }
}
```

And all the data within this is stored in an array like so..

```
var bestWishesArr = [BestWishes]()
self.bestWishesArr.append(contentsOf: result.bestWishes)
```

Now I would like to store `bestWishesArr` to Userdefaults. Not sure how to achieve that...

Comment: Use keyarchiver.  Please refer the below https://stackoverflow.com/a/37983027/1142743

Comment: No @Vinodh it doesn't seem to work. My struct is of type Decodable

Comment: its possible then y accepted the answer. without knowing/trying anything just don't  tell that its not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the second half of the `Codable` protocol. To be compatible with the `init` method the `date` property is saved differently depending on `type`

```
struct BestWish: Codable {

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case customerID = "customer_id"
        case birthDate = "birth_date"
        case anniversaryDate = "anniversary_date"
        case type
        case customerName = "customer_name"
        case mobileNumber = "mobile_number"
    }
    let customerID: Int
    let date: String
    let type: String
    let customerName : String
    let mobileNumber: Int

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        customerID = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .customerID)
        type = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
        if type == "anniversary_date" {
            date = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .anniversaryDate)
        } else {
            date = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .birthDate)
        }
        customerName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .customerName)
        mobileNumber = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .mobileNumber)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(customerID, forKey: .customerID)
        try container.encode(type, forKey: .type)
        if type == "anniversary_date" {
            try container.encode(date, forKey: .anniversaryDate)
        } else {
            try container.encode(date, forKey: .birthDate)
        }
        try container.encode(customerName, forKey: .customerName)
        try container.encode(mobileNumber, forKey: .mobileNumber)
    }
}
```

Then encode the array and write the `Data` object to `UserDefaults`

```
do {
    let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(bestWishesArr)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(jsonData, forKey:"bestWishes")
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: Once again, Thanks @vadian. The answer really helped! Have given . an upvote too...:)

Comment: and just a doubt..is there any `isExist` kind of method in json..to check if a certain key exists or not...?

Comment: Either make the property optional, or `decodeIfPresent`. **Please** read the documentation about JSON en-/decoding. It's worth it.

Comment: @v.bw don't use UserDefaults to store your app data. UserDefaults it is meant to store your app settings (i.e. UISwitch states). Just write the resulting JSON data into a json file inside your App support directory

Comment: Btw you should also store your dates as Date using the proper dateStrategyDecoding option and store mobile numbers as strings.